# Pocket PC2003 WCF Authentication Issue

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, compact-framework, pocketpc

I have created a very simple WCF service that returns a datatime stamp from SQL Server to the client but I am having problems accessing the service from a Pocket PC 2003 Psion device.

I have no issues when accessing the service from a WinCe 5 device but when I deploy the client code to PPC2003 it generates a 407 Proxy Authentication exception.

I generated the proxy class with NetCFSvcUtil.exe and imported them into the project with no issues but cant access when running PPC2003.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings />
            <services>
                <service behaviorConfiguration="TimeStampServiceBehavior"
                        name="JCB.QSmart.Mobile.DataService.ServerTime">
            <clear />
            <endpoint address="TimeStamp"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding"
                    name="TimeStamp"
                    contract="JCB.QSmart.Mobile.DataService.IServerTime"
                    listenUriMode="Explicit">
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex"
                    binding="mexHttpBinding"
                    name="mex"
                    contract="IMetadataExchange"
                    listenUriMode="Explicit">
            </endpoint>
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/QSmartV2" />
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        </service>
    </services>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TimeStampServiceBehavior">
            serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Previously I have specified a proxy on the device and that worked but the proxy hardware has broken down and the application is not working. How else can I handle the authentication?

Phil

Answer (score 1):

Http 407 is a network error refering to a proxy server on the network.

You need to set up proxy authentication in system.web see: http://www.mikebevers.be/blog/2009/06/wcf-http-407-proxy-authentication-required/

Since the WinCe is a windows OS it may be automaticaly authenticating itself to the proxy server.